# Tor not loading on OS X

Tags: mac

Attempting to use Tor results in either a bouncing Tor icon, or else it does not load. There are no messages. It simply is not working. Tried downloading twice. Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Comment: Clues in system log?  Console crash log?  Since it works for most people, you need to provide more information about what's different for you.

Comment: Where would I find the system log?

Comment: tail -f /var/log/system.log

Comment: I got the browser/SOCK proxy working on 10.10.5, but I can't get the relay working.